# Identify the default value of optional parameters for internal php functions

Tags: php

I want to identify the default setting of optional parameters for internal PHP functions.
As an example of the htmlspecialchars function. My first attempt:

```
$rf = new ReflectionFunction('htmlspecialchars');
$parameters = $rf->getParameters();
//1 => ReflectionParameter::__set_state(array('name' => "quote_style",)),

$defaultFlags = $parameters[1]->getDefaultValue();
//Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException:
// Cannot determine default value for internal functions
```

I expect as result specifically for htmlspecialchars an integer.A 2 for ENT_COMPAT or an 11 for ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401 (PHP8.1). I would like to avoid solutions that work with case distinctions based on the PHP version.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine on PHP [8.0](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=ZY09C8IwEED3QP9DBqHp0MHVaktBOouDi4ic6bUNXGPIR_37xopfeMvB8d69dWUGk7CELWzHN1zjje-xI5ReXXUT9LxFOviRnEGpgOQA1qVZERUDFkb0aF1U44O87NHv3kfxgCLWYgeBfEPQz-BHOy5Peanc9gkcgALWEyiCC6HIEsbjVH9CjHwbL3DFdSCakxPYcxtGI37aWXEH&v=8.0.17) and [8.1](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=ZY09C8IwEED3QP9DBqHp0MHVaktBOouDi4ic6bUNXGPIR_37xopfeMvB8d69dWUGk7CELWzHN1zjje-xI5ReXXUT9LxFOviRnEGpgOQA1qVZERUDFkb0aF1U44O87NHv3kfxgCLWYgeBfEPQz-BHOy5Peanc9gkcgALWEyiCC6HIEsbjVH9CjHwbL3DFdSCakxPYcxtGI37aWXEH&v=8.1.4)

Please note that it's intended to throw error for build-in functions as noted in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php#refsect1-reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue-changelog) for any PHP version prior 8.0

You can call `isDefaultValueAvailable` before that to avoid throw error (or wrap in try-catch block):

```php
$rf = new ReflectionFunction('htmlspecialchars');
$parameters = $rf->getParameters();

$defaultFlags = $parameters[1]->isDefaultValueAvailable()
    ? $parameters[1]->getDefaultValue()
    : null;

var_dump($defaultFlags);
```

[Example](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=ZY09C8IwEED3QP9DBqHp0MHVaktBOouDi4ic6bUNXGPIR_37xopfeMvB8d69dWUGk7CELWzHN1zjje-xI5ReXXUT9LxFOviRnEGpgOQA1qVZERUDFkb0aF1U44O87NHv3kfxgCLWYgeBfEPQz-BHOy5Peanc9gkcgALWEyiCC6HIEsbjVH9CjHwbL3DFdSCakxPYcxtGI37aWXEH&v=7.4.28)